# reCaptcha show error same page

Tags: php, recaptcha

How can i show error in same page?

my form page

```
<form id="freeform" method="post" action="/wp-content/themes/ecobiz/teklif.php" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
...
<?php
          require_once(ABSPATH. '/wp-content/themes/ecobiz/recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "6LeZGdESAAAAAOhZ0SRqLWXcq4TauDK9CUoZhNP8"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
....
</form>
```

teklif.php

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  }
```

Above die show up teklif.php and it's look weird. I want the die message show up in form page i mean same page. Is there any solution?
(Sorry for my English.)

Answer (score 0):

place the php code on top of your page and leave the action attribute of form element blank.

for example

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH. '/wp-content/themes/ecobiz/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "6LeZGdESAAAAAOhZ0SRqLWXcq4TauDK9CUoZhNP8";
//If form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  }
}
?>
```

I assume you have an `input="submit"` with the name attribute set as 'submit'. now place this code below.

```
<form id="freeform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
    <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: well Wordpress is PHP. so it should work, my guess is the problem lies with the name attribute of input type submit. right click and view source your code. and find this `<input type="submit" name=""/>` and tell me what is the value in `name=""`

Comment: <input name="submit" type="image" value="Submit" src="submitButton.gif" class="toggleval">

Comment: i found error type in developers.google. how can i use that? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/tips